# Why is Service Worker not running on Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, service-worker

Currently I'm trying to build a web app using the [Samsung Tab A](http://www.samsung.com/nl/business/business-products/tablets/tablets/SM-T555NZWAPHN). I thought this device would support Service Workers, cause following [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker) says Chrome for Android 55 is required to run SW.

The tablet is running Android 6.0.1 (no more updates available) and Chrome 55.0.2, but unfortunately when the code shown below runs, the 'no sw' alert pops up.. The SW works fine in Chrome on desktop (mac OS).

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((registration) => {
    alert('sw');
    console.log('ServiceWorker successful, scope: ', registration.scope);
  }).catch((err) => {
    alert('no sw');
    console.log('ServiceWorker failed: ', err);
  });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to run SW on this kind of tablet? What else is needed if Chrome 55 isn't enough? I think there is some lack of information about this topic since I can't find the answer on this .. :(

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'd already enable multiple flags via `chrome://flags` without any success..

Answer (score 13):

I was using ngrok to serve my webapp locally to my tablet. Did forget to use https..

Comment: Correct. Any service worker ran off your box (non-localhost) has to be served up via HTTPS, right?

Answer (score 3):

Go to chrome://flags and add the url like http://localhost:3000/ to the unsafe input

if you don't know just follow the picture bellow.

https://i.ibb.co/Tvwv6VN/Screenshot-20220727-223110.jpg

after this re launch your chrome or any browser.